# Looping Through Nodes In An XML File Using PHP

Tags: php, xml

Hi Stackoverflow Community - Question from an enthusiast programmer that I've researched here a great deal but still can't figure out.  Appreciate any help I can get.

I have an XML document called example.xml with the following structure...

```
<Submissions>
    <Submission>
        <Name>Submission 001</Name>
        <Entries>
            <Entry>
                <EntryId>1</EntryId>
                <Field1>Foo</Field1>
            </Entry>

            <Entry>
                <EntryId>2</EntryId>
                <Field1>Bar</Field1>
            </Entry>
        </Entries>
    </Submission>
    <Submission>
        <Name>Submission 002</Name>
        <Entries>
            <Entry>
                <EntryId>1</EntryId>
                <Field1>Foo</Field1>
            </Entry>

            <Entry>
                <EntryId>2</EntryId>
                <Field1>Bar</Field1>
            </Entry>
        </Entries>
    </Submission>
</Submissions>
```

I am using SimpleXML in PHP and would like parse the XML document and echo to the browser something that looks like this:

```
Submission 1, Entry 1, Foo
Submission 1, Entry 2, Bar
Submission 2, Entry 1, Foo
Submission 2, Entry 2, Bar
```

So basically the idea is just to loop through the XML document and associating every entry with the submission to which it belongs.

I did my research and I'm comfortable getting the entries outputted with the following code, but I can't figure out how to associate the entries with a submission.

```
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_file('example.xml');

$Submissions = $xml;

foreach ($Submissions->Submission->Entries->Entry as $Entry) {

    echo $Entry->EntryId.' , '.$Entry->Field2.' <br />';

}

?>
```

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Just a note: your XML is invalid, the opening and ending tags mismatch in `<Field1>Foo</Field2>`

Comment: thanks - I edited the xml for this post to simplify it but only changed the opening tags.  Any suggestions on how to deal with my looping issue?

Comment: Just fixed the xml - matching up opening and closing tags - dumb mistake on my part.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using XPath to get the grandparent like so

```
$submission = $Entry->xpath("../..");
```

Comment: OK. That helps.  Any suggestions for how to pull it together - not familiar with xpath in simplexml

Comment: In other words - what should I echo?

Comment: This will get you the node and you can echo any properties of it... but I suppose you need the index of `<Submission>` into `<Submissions>`? If that's the case I think you will have to use the nested loop from the other answer.

Comment: MDrollette - Thanks very much for your help.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I rarely use SimpleXML, but could you not do something like:

```
foreach ($Submissions->Submission as $Sub) {

  foreach ($Sub->Entries->Entry as $Entry) {

    echo $Sub->Name . ', ' . $Entry->EntryId.' , '.$Entry->Field2.' <br />';

  }

}
```

**EDIT:** Changed the code to correctly display the data in the Name tag (as the OP suggested in the comments below).

Comment: David - Thanks for the great suggestion...almost there.  When I plop your code into my php file I get a blank field where the $Sub variable is echoing.  What I want is for the name of the Submission - <Name> to be at the head of the line.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I figured it out!  I just added $Sub->Name to the echo statement and it's working like a charm!  Thanks, David.  Appreciate your help.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to update the answer after checking the docs, but got called away from my machine before I could. Glad it worked out for you. I'm gonna update my answer to reflect what I found out, although it is basically exactly what you just said.